# Setup Selenium webdriver Java project using semaphore CI CD Tool

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, semaphore

I’m trying to run `Selenium Webdriver` scripts in `Java` and deploy it though semaphore `CI CD` tool.

I’m using `TestNG` and `Maven`, but I’m new and don’t know how to proceed.

```
Error im getting is: \[ERROR\] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project TestAutomation: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 19 -\> \[Help 1\]00:05
\[ERROR\]
```

I want to run one jave file only, am i writing this correctly:

```
mvn -Dtest=NewTemplate test
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoGKT.png)

Comment: Your Maven is using the wrong Java version. Run `mvn --version` and see what you get - is it using the Java version **and** location you are expecting?